# php implode contact form issue

Tags: php

I want my contact form to have an option to choose recipients by the user. Therefore, I implemented the list of 12 checkboxes - each of them is representing the different recipient of the message.

Checkbox value = email adress. Then in php I used the implode function, as some other person adviced me but I can not make it work properly.

I get this error message: "Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /mywebsite.com/mail.php on line 112"

Line 112 of the code is: `$emails = implode(",",$_REQUEST['group1']);`

Ok now the html code:

```
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_one@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_two@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_three@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_four@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_five@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_six@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_seven@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_eight@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_nine@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_ten@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_eleven@mywebsite.com">
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="mail_twelve@mywebsite.com">
```

Now the php code:

```
$emails = implode(",",$_REQUEST['group1']);
$email_to = $emails;
```

Guys, any idea what might be wrong here? I will highly appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: change name="group1" to name="group1[]"

Comment: ok posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the name of the HTML field as

```
name="group1"
```

So to `implode()` it needs an array so change the above as

```
name="group1[]"
```

Do it for all the fields.